# Error while migrating SQL Server database to Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-10g

I am getting this error message while loading database capture script output in Oracle SQL Developer. The source is SQL Server 2000 and destination is Oracle 11g.
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-12899: value too large for column "ORASQL"."SS2K_SYSPROPERTIES"."VALUE" (actual: 3605, maximum: 1000)

[image]

Comment: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-12899: value too large for column "ORASQL"."SS2K_SYSPROPERTIES"."VALUE" (actual: 3605, maximum: 1000)

Comment: error message after extending

Answer (score 0):

Without having any details on the tables structure I can only point to the obvious "value too large for column", the source value is 3605 and the target can only support up to 1000.